# How can a C++ array be value-initialized?

Tags: c++, default, initializer

1) In C++, is providing the initializer list `{}` the same as `{0}`?  Will the statements:

`int x[10]={};`

`int x[10]={0};`

both produce the same array with all elements initialized to 0?

2) On systems/compilers where `NULL` is not 0, do default-value initializations of arrays of pointers set the elements to NULL or to 0?  Which of the following statements should/can be used?

`int *x[10]={NULL};`

`int *x[10]={0};`

`int *x[10]={};`

How about `new` value-initializers using empty parentheses -- do they use NULL or 0 as the initializer?

`int **x=new int*[10]();`

Comment: For #2, `nullptr` should be used if C++11.

Comment: why dont you just try it and see what you get

Comment: `NULL` is 0 on all compilers that conform to the C++ standard.

Comment: Redefining `NULL` as 1 gave me all 0s for an empty initializer list.

Comment: @chris: Only the preprocessor sees `NULL`, so changing it won't affect how the compiler value-initialises pointers.

Comment: @dreamlax, indeed, good point. It *is* proof though :p

Comment: @PreetKukreti: Because that does not always produce useful results (as implementation-defined and unspecified behavior may very across compilers and even with different flags). Best to get a quote from the standard that explains the required behavior.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes. Both of those initialisers are equivalent in functionality. The difference is that the second one explicitly initialises the first element to 0, and implicitly value-initialises all remaining elements in the array (which in the case of `int`, means setting them to 0).
2. `NULL` is `0` on all compilers that conform to the C++ standard. In this instance, all three are the same in terms of functionality. `NULL` is a macro that expands to `0`, so the first two are identical in the eyes of the compiler. I'm not sure what the deal will be with C++11, but the value-initialisation of a pointer means setting that pointer to `NULL`.